# Accessing multiple file references in Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, filereference, tca

I'm writing my first Typo3 12 extension. It should deliver a list of colors mainly. There should be some file attachments for every color record. I can attach multiple files. But I can't access them in the view.

I've got this TCA configuration:

```
'images' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'label',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'file',
        'allowed' => 'common-image-types'
    ],
],
```

There are two files added to the only existing record (so, the TCA seems to be correct).
[image]

With f:debug I get this result:
[image]
This relation will hold only the first file record. Furthermore, this structure could only hold one reference.

Because, a complete data layer is missing. I would expect something like this (foreign example):
[image]

Here's the model:
[image]

What is happening here?

- I tried to find different TCA or Model configurations.  There is only one.
- I've checked the file reference records in the database. Looks good.
- I've tried the same with other file types (downloads). Same result.

I've expected to see an object of objects (two dimensions) and not an single object (one dimension) in Fluid context.

Comment: I've got a possible solution. I added the "attach" and "detach" syntax to the model. I get all images now. 

So the issue has come with my initial Extension Builder model construction. I have chosen "image" as data type there, which results in the TCA mapping for one single file - not multiple files, I guess.